# Combining boolean operators

Tags: python

We have a 4 list:

```
lst1 = ['asd', '123', 'uniq','all']
lst2 = ['asd', '123', 'all']
lst3 = ['asd', 'al']
lst4 = ['all']
result = {}
shadow_list = []
for i in lst1:
    if statement1:
        result[i] = 0.25
    elif statement2:
        result[i] = 0.50
    elif statement3:
        result[i] = 0.75
    else:
        shadow_list.append(i)
```

I`m talking about word prevalence.

- statement1 - word from lst1 only in lst1(1/4-0.25)
- statement2- word from lst1 only in lst1 and lst2 or lst or
  lst4(2/4-0.50)
- statement3- word from lst1 only in 3 of those lists(2,3/2,4/3,4)
  3/4-0.75

So how can I combine if boolean operators in python to get the result above?

Update:

So we take word from lst1 - 'asd' and we see that this word only in 3 of 4 lists, so the spread is 3/4

Than we take '123', and we see that this word only in 2 of 4, so 2/4

Then we take 'uniq', this words only in list1, so 1/4

I need something like this "Hindu" code:

```
for i in lst1:
    if i in (lst2 and lst3 and i not in lst4) or i in (lst3 and lst 4 and not in lst2) or i in (lst2 and lst4 and not in lst3)
```

I need to check spreading of the word. We have only 4 lists. If the word only in 3 lists of 4 - it spread 3/4, if in 2 of 4 - 2/4, if it uniqs(only in one lists) 1/4
Sorry for my "stupid" english.

Comment: I need to combine bool operat. to get something like this: if we see this word only 1 time - 0.25, 2 times - 0.50, 3 times-0.75. I need to know the words spread.

Comment: What "word" are we talking about? How does being in list1 and list2 give you 2/4?

Comment: Please edit your question so it is clear what are you asking for.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, check my edited answer to see if works for you.

Comment: @sparkandshine, YEA man, exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I understand what you want. So, it is better to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter),

```
import collections
import itertools

s1 = set(['asd', '123', 'uniq','all'])
s2 = set(['asd', '123', 'all'])
s3 = set(['asd', 'all'])
s4 = set(['all'])

l = [s1, s2, s3, s4]
nrof_lists = len(l) 

result = {k : v*1.0/nrof_lists for k, v in collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)).items()}

print(result)
{'uniq': 0.25, 'all': 1.0, '123': 0.5, 'asd': 0.75}
```

---

A basic solution,

```
s1 = set(['asd', '123', 'uniq','all'])
s2 = set(['asd', '123', 'all'])
s3 = set(['asd', 'all'])
s4 = set(['all'])

result = {}
shadow_list = []

l = [s1, s2, s3, s4]
nrof_lists = len(l)

for word in s1:
    times = sum([word in s for s in l])

    if times:
        result[word] = times*1.0/nrof_lists
    else:
        shadow_list.append(word)

# Output
print(result)
{'123': 0.5, 'all': 1.0, 'uniq': 0.25, 'asd': 0.75}
print(shadow_list)
[]
```

Comment: times = sum( word in s for s in l)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thx, edited the answer.

Comment: You can also remove the list call in merged, Counter will work fine passing a chain object.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, `collections.Counter(lists)` doesn't work for `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`.

Comment: `{k : v*1.0/nrof_lists for k, v in collections.Counter(itertools.chain(*l)).items()}` will work fine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thx again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @sparkandshine, Perfect, but, if we found the word two or more times in one list, in result we can see only one duplicate of this word, so I need to see all of them.

Comment: @prisethesun13, in such a case, replace `set` with `list`.

Comment: @sparkandshine, doesn`t work, I have this output {'123': 0.5, 'all': 1.0, 'uniq': 0.25, 'asd': 1.0}

Answer (score 0):

A `Counter` is perfect for this:

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
word_sets = [
    # Use sets (with curly brackets: {}) to prevent duplicates, i.e. {'abc'} == {'abc', 'abc'}
    {'asd', '123', 'uniq', 'all'},
    {'asd', '123', 'all'},
    {'asd', 'all'},
    {'all'}
]

for word_set in word_sets:
    counter.update(word_set)
print counter  # Counter({'all': 4, 'asd': 3, '123': 2, 'uniq': 1})

def spread(word):
    return float(counter[word]) / len(word_sets)

for word in word_sets[0]:
    print(word, spread(word))
```

Output of the end:

```
('123', 0.5)
('all', 1.0)
('uniq', 0.25)
('asd', 0.75)
```

Comment: still can't get the result I need. If I add one more word - 'asd' to first list, I just get this output - ('123', 0.5)
('all', 1.0)
('uniq', 0.25)
('asd', 0.75)

Comment: If you want to count duplicates within a word set then replace curly brackets `{}` with square brackets `[]` to use lists instead.

Comment: I did it, but then word frequency increases, I don`t need it. I just need to know word frequency  in other 3 list. 
if there is two words 'asd' in list1, I need the output like ('asd', 0.75)...('asd', 0.75)

Comment: You want `asd` to appear twice? Why?

Comment: I`m trying to solve " classification task".

Comment: The list will be a parsed pdf article.

Comment: "I just need to know word frequency in other 3 list. " If that's true, then your desired outcome should be `('123', 0.33)
('all', 1.0)
('uniq', 0)
('asd', 0.67)`

Comment: Replace `word_sets[0]` at the end with `['asd', '123', 'uniq', 'all', 'asd']` and leave the rest of the code as it is in the answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: yep, exactly what I need. Thank you!